# Recipes to implement a self-retained network lib

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

I would like to implement a self-retained network lib that can be used also with ARC.

The calling code for this lib should be like the following.

```
- (void)downloadData {

    NSURL *url = // alloc-init
    NetworkFetcher *networkFetcher = [[NetworkFetcher alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [networkFetcher startWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data){
        _fetchedData = data;
    }];
    // under ARC it will put a release call for the networkFetcher here
}
```

This approach is used by `TWRequest` (if I am not wrong it's deprecated now) class in Twitter framework. The advantage is that the caller does not need to maintain the fetcher alive itself.

Some details. The `startWithCompletionHandler` copies the block for future reuse. When the request has finished, the fetcheher releases the block settima it to nil.

So, what the approach I need to follow so the fetcher can be self-retained? Any best pratice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a "private" property

```
@interface NetworkFetcher ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NetworkFetcher *selfRef;
@end
```

in a class extension to the `NetworkFetcher` class. In `startWithCompletionHandler`, you set

```
self.selfRef = self;
```

to prevent the object from being deallocated. When the request has finished and the completion block has been called, set

```
self.selfRef = nil;
```

to destroy the retain cycle.

Comment: @flexaddicted: You are right, it should be a "private" property that is only visible to the implementation, and therefore be defined in a class extension. - Answer updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the technique described by Martin R which basically imitates the older `retain` and `release` but there are also other methods.

You can capture the `fetcher` in the `completionHandler`. Just use `self` anywhere in the completion handler and don't forget to release the block when it has been called. This is a bit less readable then using a property but it follows the same principle

Another method is to have a singleton (mutable) array of active fetchers. Adding/Removing follows the same principle as with `self.selfRef` property.

With a singleton array there is one big advantage - you can access the fetchers whenever you want - cancel them or just get the number of active fetchers (to limit number of simultaneous downloads, for example).

Comment: When you say *capture the fetcher in the completionHandler*, do you mean capture *self* within the block? Or capture *self* within the fetcher class?